# Fetch Super-parent list or show parent if 1 level is absent

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

I have a table in oracle 11G as -

```
ID  NAME        TYPE    DESCRIPTION PARENTID
1   INDIA       1       COUNTRY 
2   ZONE_A      2       REGION      1
3   ZONE_B      2       REGION      1
4   ZONE_C      2       REGION      1
5   CITY_1      3       CITY        2
6   CITY_2      3       CITY        2
7   CITY_3      3       CITY        3
8   CITY_4      3       CITY        3
9   BRANCH_1    4       BRANCH      5
10  BRANCH_2    4       BRANCH      5
11  BRANCH_3    4       BRANCH      6
12  BRANCH_4    4       BRANCH      6
13  BRANCH_5    4       BRANCH      3
```

As you can see here Branches have Cities as their parent but sometimes they might not have any City as their parent but direct Regions as their parent instead.

I need to show the Regions to which Branches belongs. I have created the query to show the super parent Region as -

```
SELECT C1.NAME, C3.NAME
FROM CTE C1
JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.PARENTID = C2.ID
JOIN CTE C3 ON C2.PARENTID = C3.ID
WHERE C1.DESCRIPTION = 'BRANCH';
```

This is giving me the correct region but messing up with Branches not having any parent i.e. any row for City.

```
BRANCHES    PARENT  SUPER_PARENT
BRANCH_5    ZONE_B  INDIA
BRANCH_3    CITY_2  ZONE_A
BRANCH_4    CITY_2  ZONE_A
BRANCH_1    CITY_1  ZONE_A
BRANCH_2    CITY_1  ZONE_A
```

**Expected Output**

How can I show ZONE_B under SUPER_PARENT column as this is the requirement to show the Branches with their correct Regions only.

```
BRANCHES    SUPER_PARENT
BRANCH_5    ZONE_B
BRANCH_3    ZONE_A
BRANCH_4    ZONE_A
BRANCH_1    ZONE_A
BRANCH_2    ZONE_A
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=80bcb901b933ee815b7b6c8eb8d2e6a4) is the fiddle for your refernece.

Comment: i would prefer to have normalized data instead of having the above data with everything in one table as manipulating the same data will be more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it more efficiently using a hierarchical query (which requires no joins):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, NAME, TYPE, DESCRIPTION, PARENTID ) AS
  SELECT 1,  'INDIA',    1, 'COUNTRY', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  'ZONE_A',   2, 'REGION',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  'ZONE_B',   2, 'REGION',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,  'ZONE_C',   2, 'REGION',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,  'CITY_1',   3, 'CITY',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,  'CITY_2',   3, 'CITY',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7,  'CITY_3',   3, 'CITY',    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8,  'CITY_4',   3, 'CITY',    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9,  'BRANCH_1', 4, 'BRANCH',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'BRANCH_2', 4, 'BRANCH',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'BRANCH_3', 4, 'BRANCH',  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'BRANCH_4', 4, 'BRANCH',  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 'BRANCH_5', 4, 'BRANCH',  3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( name ) AS branch,
       PRIOR name AS parent,
       name AS super_parent
FROM   table_name
WHERE LEVEL = 3
START WITH description = 'BRANCH'
CONNECT BY id = PRIOR parentid
```

**Output**:

> ```
> BRANCH   | PARENT | SUPER_PARENT
> :------- | :----- | :-----------
> BRANCH_1 | CITY_1 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_2 | CITY_1 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_3 | CITY_2 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_4 | CITY_2 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_5 | ZONE_B | INDIA
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d22aadc94f037c75fdcbbb060c06a1d9)*

**Query 2**:

If you just want the associated regions:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( name ) AS branch,
       name AS super_parent
FROM   table_name
WHERE  description     = 'REGION'
START WITH description = 'BRANCH'
CONNECT BY id = PRIOR parentid
```

**Output**:

> ```
> BRANCH   | SUPER_PARENT
> :------- | :-----------
> BRANCH_1 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_2 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_3 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_4 | ZONE_A      
> BRANCH_5 | ZONE_B
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2b4b7cf10df0e4baf3805e441cabce1)*

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution as I wanted a oracle specific solution only. However Is there any way to tweak this query as the expected output?

Comment: That was awesome.

Comment: A question just clicked in my mind. Though we are not writing any join here, does this really mean this query will not use self join while get converted to relational algebra? Does connect by clause never converts to self join and reads table only once?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Look at the Explain Plan [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f5c40ce2aad78186d844210a478a2125); there is no join and only a single table scan. You can compare it to the explain plan for other answers where there are both multiple joins and table scans.

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data and description, the following returns the region name:

```
SELECT B.NAME as BRANCH,
       COALESCE(BP2.NAME, BP.NAME) as REGION_NAME
FROM CTE B LEFT JOIN
     CTE BP
     ON B.PARENTID = BP.ID LEFT JOIN
     CTE BP2
     ON BP.PARENTID = BP2.ID AND BP2.DESCRIPTION = 'REGION'
WHERE B.DESCRIPTION = 'BRANCH';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check while joining via case if that type on join is immediate previous parent or not if not like branch to region is not concurrent then have those 2 columns as same names else parent

```
      SELECT C1.NAME, Case 
            when C1.Type-1 != 
       C2.Type THEN C1.NAME 
       ELSE C3.NAME END
    FROM CTE C1
   JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.PARENTID = C2.ID
  JOIN CTE C3 ON C2.PARENTID = C3.ID
    WHERE C1.DESCRIPTION = 'BRANCH';
```